# Excel VBA: "Compile Error: Wrong Number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Tags: excel, vba, compilation

I'm getting a compile error when running the code below. The goal of the code is to move the cursor and click on cells in the excel doc. The mouse_event seems to be causing the issue but I'm not sure why (perhaps the wrong formatting?).

The VBA editor is also highlighting the first two lines red, which I'm not sure why it's doing that.

Thank you for your help!

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As LongPtr, ByVal y As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As LongPtr, ByVal dx As LongPtr, ByVal dy As LongPtr, ByVal cButtons As LongPtr, ByVal dwExtraInfo As LongPtr) 

Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As LongPtr = &H8
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As LongPtr = &H10

Sub MoveMousePlease()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 9999
    'For Info, number of iteration
    'Cells(1, 1) = i
    
    If Cells(3, 5) = "" Then
        SetCursorPos 350, 300 'x and y position
        mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
        mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
        WaitPlease
        
        
        SetCursorPos 350, 360 'x and y position
        mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
        mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
        WaitPlease
        
        SetCursorPos 350, 420 'x and y position
        mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
        mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
        WaitPlease
        
        SetCursorPos 350, 480 'x and y position
        mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
        mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
        WaitPlease
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
    Next i
End Sub


Sub WaitPlease()
    Dim sngWaitEnd As Single
    sngWaitEnd = Timer + 5
    Do
      DoEvents
      Cells(3, 3).Value = Timer
    Loop Until Timer >= sngWaitEnd
End Sub
```

Comment: 32- or 64-bit Excel?

Answer (score 1):

First off, don't do that. You can do everything using VBA commands without moving the mouse and simulating clicks.

If you [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event) you will find that they say not to use `mouse_event` in favor of [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput)

Now the answer:

**Your code works in 64-bit Excel.** This means that you are using a 32-bit host which requires a different signature.

Try this:

```
Public Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Boolean
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As LongPtr, ByVal dx As LongPtr, ByVal dy As LongPtr, ByVal cButtons As LongPtr, ByVal dwExtraInfo As LongPtr)
```